# Enum Skeleton Table

Tags: java, enums, skeleton-code

Hello I'm just wondering if there is anyone that could make sense of this java skeleton code table for an enum class.
Table:

[image]

My code currently is this:

```
public enum SkyCondition
{
    SUNNY,
    SNOWY,
    CLOUDY,
    RAINY
}
```

Is that it? or am I supposed to incorporate the `int` in some way?
Thank you.

Comment: Seems like `SkyCondition` was intended to be a bunch of old-style `int` constants in some class. But for a typical Java implementation, your code should be enough, as mentioned in Alex Rudenko's answer below. The only exception would be if your `int` values have to be set to specific, non-default, values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html) includes two properties by default:

```
public final String name(); // name like SUNNY, SNOWY, CLOUDY, RAINY
public final int ordinal(); // the position in enum declaration: 0 - for SUNNY, 1 - SNOWY, etc.
```

so, `int` is already incorporated into `enum`.

Comment: Perfect that is kind of what I thought, but just wanted to double check. Thank you very much!